# select_for_update not working even though it is inside a transaction

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to fetch a customer object from the db. I have writtern a separate service for that. But my problem is that select_for_update is not working when i try to get customer through it but raw orm query works.

Error that i am getting

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.
```

Customer service

```
class CustomerService:
    @staticmethod
    def get_customer(select_for_update=False, **params_dict) -> Customer:
        """
        param: customer mobile number
        return: Customer object
        raises exception INVALID_CUSTOMER if customer does not exist
        """
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects
            if select_for_update:
                customer = customer.select_for_update()
            customer = customer.get(**params_dict)
            return customer
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            raise ParseException(INVALID_CUSTOMER, errors='INVALID_CUSTOMER')
```

This doesn't work-

```
 @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = CustomerService.get_customer({"id": customer_id}, select_for_update=True)
```

but this does

```
@transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.select_for_update().get(id=customer_id)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            raise ParseException(INVALID_CUSTOMER, errors='INVALID_CUSTOMER')
```

Comment: `select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.` I think it's conflicting between your argument `select_for_update` and method `select_for_update()` try to change name of argument

Comment: The problem was i was not expanding the dict into key value pairs. ```customer = CustomerService.get_customer(**{"id": customer_id}, select_for_update=True)```